# Make an array of objects inside object as multiple objects JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, arrayobject

I need to transform an array of objects in multiple objects inside parent object:

Actual object:

```
{
name: 'John Doe',
Age: 50,
email: 'j@gmail.com'
wishlist: [
   {product1 : 1},
   {product2 : 3},
   {product3 : 5},
   {product4 : 2},
 ]
}
```

Goal:

```
{

name: 'John Doe',
Age: 50,
email: 'j@gmail.com',
product1 : 1,
product2 : 3,
product3 : 5,
product4 : 2,

}
```

Does anyone know how to do that?
kind regards,

Comment: Will wishlist objects (e.g. `{product1 : 1}` ) ever have more than one entry?

Comment: I want something reverse of this. could anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `reduce()` method on wishlist array and then create final object using `spread` operator.

```js
const myObj = {
name: 'John Doe',
Age: 50,
email: 'j@gmail.com',
wishlist: [
   {product1 : 1},
   {product2 : 3},
   {product3 : 5},
   {product4 : 2},
 ]
}

const processData = (data) => {
  const wishlist = data.wishlist.reduce((result, obj) => {
     return {...result, ...obj};
  }, {});
  const finalObj = {...data, ...wishlist};
  delete finalObj.wishlist;
  return finalObj;
}

console.log(processData(myObj));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can merge all products, then merge them with the object and then delete the initial array. I think this way is better, not to modify the original object while iterating one of its attributes.

```js
let products = {} 
for (let product of obj.wishlist)
   products = {...products, ...product}
obj = {...obj, ...products}
delete obj.wishlist
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to grab your `wishlist` array, and an object of properties excluding your whishlist array (stored in `r`), which you can then use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to merge all the objects from your wishlist array into your `r` object:

```js
const {wishlist, ...r} = { name: 'John Doe', Age: 50, email: 'j@gmail.com', wishlist: [ {product1 : 1}, {product2 : 3}, {product3 : 5}, {product4 : 2}, ] };

const res = Object.assign(r, ...wishlist);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
var obj = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  Age: 50,
  email: 'j@gmail.com',
  wishlist: [{ product1: 1 }, { product2: 3 }, { product3: 5 }, { product4: 2 }]
};

var newObj = Object.assign({}, ...obj.wishlist);
delete obj.wishlist;

const finalObj = { ...obj, ...newObj };
console.log(finalObj);
```

Comment: You can't delete wishlist property of original obj.

Comment: @RahulKumar What do you mean by can't? This code appears to work. The question doesn't mention anything about not modifying the original object. Do you just mean that it would be better practice not to? Or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: It's recommended to not modify original object while following best coding practices. In his code that object might be used somewhere else and it can cause issue.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone was looking for a more generic answer.

I have written code to transform an Object or an Array inside another Object or an Array.

Overkill if you ask me.

```js
const sample = [{
  name: 'John Doe',
  Age: 50,
  email: 'j@gmail.com',
  wishlist: [{ product1: 1 }, { product2: 3 }, { product3: 5 }, { product4: 2 }]
}];

const transformArray = array => {
    let obj = {};
    array.forEach(item => {
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            obj = { ...obj, ...transformArray(item)};
        } else if (typeof item == 'object') {
            obj = { ...obj, ...transformObj(item)};
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

const transformObj = object => {
    let obj = {};
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
        const item = object[key];
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            obj = { ...obj, ...transformArray(item) };
        } else if (typeof item == 'object') {
            obj = { ...obj, ...transformObj(item) };
        } else {
            obj = { ...obj, [key]: item };
        }
    });
    return obj;
}

console.log(transformObj(sample));
```